# How can I increase the size of the hard disk used by my Virtual Machine Manager (VMM) vm?

Tags: scvmm

In Virtual Machine Manager admin console, I used the 'New virtual machine' wizard and created a machine from an existing template.

When I got to the Configure Hardware step, I selected the primary hard disk (which is a dynamic) disk and tried to increase it's maximum size, but this control is disabled so I can't increase it.

[image]

It's not big enough for my purposes. how do I increase the maximum size of the hard-disk?

Thanks.

Edit: I am able to add a second hard disk of a size I specify. That's not useful though as I'm trying to install some software, some of which insists on being on drive C.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual disks cannot be edited when the virtual machine is running or in a saved state. Stop the virtual machine, then try again.

A virtual disk also cannot be edited when any checkpoints exist. You will have to delete all existing checkpoints to be able to resize the disk. However, the Channel drop-down list is only disabled (as in the above screenshot) when the VM is running.

Answer (score 0):

System drives cannot be increased in size this way with basic operating system tools.  You can, however, Get Creative.  One approach is to use this utility:  http://h0bbel.p0ggel.org/howto-using-extpart-to-expand-windows-server-2003-vm-boot-volume.  Says it's for Dell, but I've used it on VMs before.

Comment: Looks like that might help people using VMWare with a 2003 32 bit machine. I'm using Virtual Machine Manager though and, I didn't mention it before, but my VM has a Windows7 64 bit OS.